# Resize table header to match the table body generated by ASP.net GridView

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/byB9d/3282/

Script:

```
function removeClassName (elem, className) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace(className, "").trim();
}

function addCSSClass (elem, className) {
    removeClassName (elem, className);
    elem.className = (elem.className + " " + className).trim();
}

String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace( /^\s+|\s+$/, "" );
}

function stripedTable() {
    if (document.getElementById && document.getElementsByTagName) {  
        var allTables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
        if (!allTables) { return; }

        for (var i = 0; i < allTables.length; i++) {
            if (allTables[i].className.match(/[\w\s ]*scrollTable[\w\s ]*/)) {
                var trs = allTables[i].getElementsByTagName("tr");
                for (var j = 0; j < trs.length; j++) {
                    removeClassName(trs[j], 'alternateRow');
                    addCSSClass(trs[j], 'normalRow');
                }
                for (var k = 0; k < trs.length; k += 2) {
                    removeClassName(trs[k], 'normalRow');
                    addCSSClass(trs[k], 'alternateRow');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

window.onload = function() { stripedTable(); }
```

How can I make sure the header matches with the body.

Comment: this is complicated, you should probably google for plugins that do it, and perhaps try to look how they do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to change your table structure. You can make a fixed table header without separating it into 2 tables.

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container-inner">

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><div class="th-inner">First</div></th>
                    <th><div class="th-inner">Second</div></th>
                    <th><div class="th-inner">Third</div></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <!-- Your table content here -->
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.container {
    position: relative; /* could be absolute or relative */
    padding-top: 30px; /* height of header */
    height: 200px; /* the height your table should be */
}

.container-inner {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.th-inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    line-height: 30px; /* height of header */
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vy0j9Lp6/1/)

Source, more info and examples of other fixed table headers can be found [here](http://salzerdesign.com/test/fixedTable.html).

Comment: Thank you. This is actually generated using a GridView from asp.net page.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge does that mean you are not able to change the html structure?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vy0j9Lp6/2/ This is generated code... unfortunately I am not able to change the HTML structure :/ That is why I am having a tough time...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vy0j9Lp6/3/ something like this works but it's all jumbled up, the TH.

Comment: This is what I currently have: http://jsfiddle.net/gxxn9bkt/ < this code is what the full generated page looks like. I added a scrollbar in the outer DIV but now trying to make the header stick on DIV scroll. If I can just do it on the table itself, I can remove all the extra divs and table.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge Incase your issue was solved, please mark an answer as correct to close your question, or post an answer by yourself if you found a different solution. If your issue was not solved, please provide us with more info on the issue.

Comment: Didn't see this one. Thanks.

Comment: I did use some of the code from your answer and used javascript to achieve the fixed header. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are 7 items in your header and only 6 in the td's, therefore, it will never match up.

Strip out all of your CSS and the headers line up with the rest of the table.
The issue is sure to be in the CSS.

Comment: Which CSS are you referring to? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in CSS. Just remove the `display: block` from `html>body thead.fixedHeader tr` and `html>body tbody.scrollContent`.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/byB9d/3307/).

Comment: I added multiple rows: http://jsfiddle.net/byB9d/3309/ and it doesn't show the rest of them :/

Comment: This is what I currently have: http://jsfiddle.net/gxxn9bkt/ < this code is what the full generated page looks like. I added a scrollbar in the outer DIV but now trying to make the header stick on DIV scroll. If I can just do it on the table itself, I can remove all the extra divs and table.